# How to Join four Tables?

Tags: oracle

I need to join three tables into the sale table, I tried left join but it does not join properly. can you guys plz give a solution.
[image]

```
Sale Tabel
MSISSND    Agent_ID    Connection_Date   District
3455         22           22-Jan-2020      abc
1222         22           12-Feb-2020      abc 
4562         25           23-Feb-2020      zxy
8907         23           12-Mar-2020      rty 

Agent Tabel
Agent_ID  Agent_name  Distributor_ID   Distributor_name
22         nikon          12              A-Z
23         cannon         13              tech
25         hp             14              hp-tech

Customer Tabel
MSISSND     Name     Address
3455        nilak    adcd
4562        suman    sdfg
8907        nizar    ewrt
1222        rowan    fgsk

Target Tabel
Distributor_ID    District    Month     Target
12                  abc       Jan_2020    10
12                  abc       Feb_2020    15
13                  rty       Feb_2020    20
14                  zxy       Mar_2020    24

Output_final table will be
MSISSND   Agent_Id  Agent_name   Conection_Date  Connection_MON_YEAR  District  Distributor_ID  Distibutor_name  Target   Name    Address
3455       22         nikon        22-Jan-2020       Jan-2020            abc    12                     A-Z         10      nilak      adcd
```

Comment: `To_char(trunc(` is useless in the JOIN condition . Just `trunc(` is fine in your case.

Comment: I have sales daily, but the target table has a monthly base. So I need to match target to sale tabel

Comment: Yes, then `... ON TRUNC(a.connection_date, 'MONTH') = TRUNC(n.month,'MONTH')` should be fine.

Comment: then how to get my final table, it does not give the correct final table

Comment: @ORA_Dentist can plz give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have not given us anything about the data types or the constraints you are using.  You may also want to look at the normalization and the business rules again.  (But maybe that's something to ask in another question)
However, you could do something like:

```
select 
  S.msissnd
, A.agentid, A.agentname
, to_char( S.connectiondate, 'DD-Mon-YYYY' ) as Connection_Date
, to_char( T.month_, 'Mon-YYYY' ) as Connection_MON_YEAR
, T.district, T.distributorid
, A.distributorname
, T.target
, C.name_, C.address 
from sale S
  join agent A on S.agentid = A.agentid
  join customer C on S.msissnd = C.msissnd
  join target T on A.distributorid = T.distributorid
    and to_char( S.connectiondate, 'MM' ) = to_char( T.month_, 'MM' )
;

-- result
   MSISSND    AGENTID    AGENTNAME    CONNECTION_DATE    CONNECTION_MON_YEAR    DISTRICT    DISTRIBUTORID    DISTRIBUTORNAME    TARGET    NAME_    ADDRESS 
__________ __________ ____________ __________________ ______________________ ___________ ________________ __________________ _________ ________ __________ 
      3455         22 nikon        22-Jan-2020        Jan-2020               abc                       12 A-Z                       10 nilak    adcd       
      1222         22 nikon        12-Feb-2020        Feb-2020               abc                       12 A-Z                       15 rowan    fgsk
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b564e747ba653a6368bd6963fb711643).

If the "Month" in your TARGET table is a VARCHAR2() type, you could add a virtual column containing a date, so you don't need to write an explicit conversion into your query.

```
-- eg
SQL> alter table target
  2  add when_ date generated always as (
  3    to_date( Month, 'MON_YYYY') 
  4  ) virtual ;
```

Comment: need to consider district also, each district target different. Agent_ID is NUMBER, Conection Data is DATE , MSISSND is VARCHAR

Comment: You will get all rows from SALE in the output, once you have defined TARGETs for every district and connection_date (in SALE).  (In other words: Your test data do not contain targets for all sales.)

Comment: In your earlier comment, you wrote: "need to consider district also ..." - you need to normalise the tables eg table AGENT: distributor_name cannot be determined by agent_id (which is probably the primary key for this table).